# Solving a set of ODE with SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I'm trying to solve a set of ODE to simulate starch hydrolysis by amylases (enzymes). When I try to solve the set of equation, I get a

```
lsoda--  at current t (=r1), mxstep (=i1) steps   
       taken on this call before reaching tout     
      In above message,  I1 =       500
      In above message,  R1 =  0.6333483931400E+00
Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
```

error. The code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def TemperatureProfile (timeandtemp,t) :

    if t==0.0 :
        T = 273.15+55
    elif t>0.0 and t<9.0 :
        T = 273.15+55+t
    elif t>= 9.0 and t<=9.0+timeandtemp[0][0] :
        T = 273.15+ timeandtemp[0][1]
    elif t>9.0+timeandtemp[0][0] and t<9.0+timeandtemp[0][0]+8.0 :
        T = 273.15+ timeandtemp[0][1]+t
    elif t>=9.0+timeandtemp[0][0]+8.0 and t<=9.0+timeandtemp[0][0]+8.0+timeandtemp[1][0] :
        T = 273.15+timeandtemp[1][1]
    elif t>9.0+timeandtemp[0][0]+8.0+timeandtemp[1][0] and t<9.0+timeandtemp[0][0]+8.0+timeandtemp[1][0]+6:
        T = 273.15+ timeandtemp[1][1]+t
    elif t>=9.0+timeandtemp[0][0]+8.0+timeandtemp[1][0]+6 and  t<9.0+timeandtemp[0][0]+8.0+timeandtemp[1][0]+6 :
        T = 273.15+timeandtemp[2][1]

    return T

def Flux (ci,temperature) :

    '''
        Constants
    '''
    K_gel1 = 5.7*10**31
    K_gel2 = 3.1*10**14

    k_glc = 0.023
    k_glc2 = 2.9*10**-8
    k_alphamal = 0.389
    k_betamal = 0.137
    k_alphamal2 = 1.2*10**-7
    k_betamal2 = 8.4*10**-8
    k_mlt = 0.117
    k_mlt2 = 1.5*10**-8
    k_dex = 0.317
    k_degalpha = 6.9*10**30 
    E_degalpha = 224.2
    k_degbeta = 7.6*10**60
    E_degbeta = 410.7


    starchUG = ci[0]
    starchG = ci[1]
    glc = ci[2]
    mal = ci[3]
    mlt = ci[4]
    dex = ci[5]
    enzA = ci[6]
    enzB = ci[7]


    '''
        Relative activities
    '''
    if temperature < 336.15 :
        a_alpha = -0.0011*temperature**3 + 1.091*temperature**2 - 352.89*temperature + 38008.3
        a_beta = 0.049*temperature - 13.9 
    else :
        a_alpha = 0.0055*temperature**3 - 5.663*temperature**2+ 1941.9*temperature- 221864 
        a_beta = 0.374*temperature + 128.3 

    ''' 
        Equations
    '''
    if temperature < 333.15 :
        r_gel = K_gel1*starchUG
    else :
        r_gel = K_gel2*starchUG

    r_glc = k_glc*a_alpha*glc
    r_mal = (k_alphamal*a_alpha+k_betamal*a_beta)*starchG
    r_mlt = k_mlt*a_alpha*starchG
    r_dex = k_dex*a_alpha*starchG
    r_glc2 = k_glc2*a_alpha*dex
    r_mal2 = k_alphamal2*a_alpha*dex+k_betamal2*a_beta*dex
    r_mlt2 = k_mlt2*a_alpha*dex
    r_degA = k_degalpha*math.exp(-E_degalpha/(8.3145*temperature))*enzA
    r_degB = k_degbeta*math.exp(-E_degbeta/(8.3145*temperature))*enzB
    r_acA = k_degalpha*math.exp(-E_degalpha/(8.3145*temperature))*a_alpha*enzA
    r_acB = k_degbeta*math.exp(-E_degbeta/(8.3145*temperature))*a_beta*enzB

    return np.array([r_glc,r_mal,r_mlt, r_dex, r_glc2, r_mal2, r_mlt2, r_degA, r_degB, r_acA, r_acB])




def Secmembre (ci,t,tempProf) :


    temperature = TemperatureProfile(tempProf,t)

    mS = np.mat([
[-1, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[1, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], 
[0, 1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], 
[0, 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0], 
[0, 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0], 
[0, 0,  0,  0,  1,  -1, -1, -1, 0,  0,  0]])

    mS = np.transpose(mS)
    mS = np.array(mS)
    metabos = Flux(ci,temperature)
    varMetabos = np.dot(metabos,mS)

    return varMetabos



# Initial conditions


initCond = []

temperatureProfile = ((30,64),(30,72),(5,78)) # Temperature steps in minutes

t0 = 0
tf  = temperatureProfile[0][0]+temperatureProfile[1][0]+temperatureProfile[2][0]+9+8+6
nbPoints = 100

timeProfile = np.linspace(t0,tf,nbPoints)
print timeProfile
initCond.append(113.5)
initCond.append(0)
initCond.append(4)
initCond.append(5)
initCond.append(0)
initCond.append(0)
initCond.append(80000)
initCond.append(80000)

initCond=np.array(initCond)

result = odeint(Secmembre,initCond,timeProfile,args=(temperatureProfile,))
```

When working on Matlab I used to solve with ode23tb. I think odeint is not the right solver but I don't know which one to use. Maybe someone is familiar with this type of equation ?

Comment: Double-check your equations: if you solve only up to `tf = 0.1`, there is no error. However, the solutions are exponentially increasing, which is not physical. Your probably get the error because the solver sees that the solutions eventually become larger than the maximum possible floating point value (~ 1e308).

Comment: In particular, `Secmembre` returns derivatives for 6 variables, but the initial condition has 8 variables. (odeint assumes the unspecified 2 variables have zero derivative)

Answer (score -1):

Overall, python, specifically scipy, is not as optimized for solving ODEs as MATLAB is.

Regarding your error:

```
lsoda--  at current t (=r1), mxstep (=i1) steps   
       taken on this call before reaching tout     
      In above message,  I1 =       500
      In above message,  R1 =  0.6333483931400E+00
Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
```

The way the solver works is that it has internally defined steps. So, say for example, you are calling your solver at 0(=initial), 1,2,3,... The solver will return values at those points, but internally, it might solve the ODE first at 0, then 0.00000001, 0.00000002, 0.00000003, 0.0001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1, etc. (All the numbers are made up for the sake of example.) But, there is a limit to the number of steps the solver will take (understandably, to avoid possible infinite loops or very very long runtimes).

Your error is saying that your solver has reached the maximum number of steps [mxstep (=i1(=500)), but has still not gotten a result within its internally defined acceptable error, so it stops and throws an error.

Recommendations: adjust your solver for it to be given more steps (set nstep in odeint), barring that, adjust the internal tolerance, perhaps you don't need it as exact as the solver wants to give you, finally consider using the ode instead of odeint (more options).

Further Reading:

[NumPy for Matlab Users](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-0c3c49ec7eef424bd3d361e5d8e2955f533750d6)

[MATLAB doc on ODE23tb (to help set ode settings)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23tb.html)